# QGIS Project variable and PostgreSQL connection

Tags: qgis, postgresql

Is it possible to use project variable in the PostgreSQL database connection in QGIS?

Usecase: Each user will set his/her `db_user` variable as part of the project. Once the project is shared among users, everybody will access the PostgreSQL database using assigned user.

Talking about project variables: I mean those, which are to be set in `Project -> Properties` and `ɛ Variables`

Comment: Description not complete (cut for unknown reason). Edit, plz.

Comment: Sorry about that, should be better now.

Comment: I think you should look at PG Services file. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/libpq-pgservice.html

Answer (score 2):

QGIS variables are effective after you open layers sources from QGIS project not before so it's not possible to provide connexion information here to my knowledge.

You should use PostgreSQL Service connection file instead. It avoids storing database informations within the project and instead use the configuration file to provide connection informations.

See official QGIS documentation https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/opening_data.html#postgresql-service-connection-file and official PostgreSQL doc https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/libpq-pgservice.html